# Усекаются ли данные при превышении их размера при использовании типа CHAR?

Tags: mysql

В книге про тип данных VARCHAR сказано, что если присвоить строковое значение длиннее позволенного, то оно будет усечено до максимальной длины, объявленной в определении таблицы.
**Вопрос: Такой же механизм и при использовании типа CHAR? Т.е. усекаются ли данные при превышении их размера при использовании типа CHAR?**

Comment: *про тип данных VARCHAR сказано, что если присвоить строковое значение длиннее позволенного, то оно будет усечено до максимальной длины* Поведение зависит от SQL Mode. Если STRICT - то генерируется ошибка `ERROR 1406 (22001): Data too long for column ...`, иначе генерируется предупреждение и значение усекается. *Такой же механизм и при использовании типа CHAR?* Абсолютно такой же.

Comment: @Akina спасибо. Можете написать это как ответ, и я помечу как решение